# Implementing generic method from an interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface

I am trying to implement simple queue in Java from an interface, but I'm getting an error:

```
Error:(9, 17) java: name clash: enqueue(T) in main.QueueImpl and enqueue(java.lang.Object) in main.Queue have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Here is my code:

Interface:

```
public interface Queue<T> {

    void enqueue(T o);

    T dequeue();

    int size();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class QueueImpl<T> implements Queue {
LinkedList<T> queue = new LinkedList<>();

@Override
public void enqueue(T o) {
    queue.add(o);
}

@Override
public T dequeue() {
    return queue.poll();
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return queue.size();
 }
}
```

What's the problem with implementing enqueue method?

Comment: You're using generics, so you don't want to implement `Queue`, you want to implement `Queue<T>`. Silly typo, easy to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your implementation to pass the generic to the ***interface***. Like,

```
public class QueueImpl<T> implements Queue<T> {
```

As is, it knows `Queue` is generic, but it's treated as a **raw type**.

Comment: That's it, thank You.